# display a div on hover of an item such that items inside div should be clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
$().ready(function() {

  // Case : 1
  $("li.products").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents(".cotnainer-fluid").next().toggleClass("show");
    //$("#category-list").css("opacity","1 !important");
  });
})
```

```css
div.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 379px;
}
div.banner>.row {
  padding: 0 35px;
}
/* .menu{
 background: transparent;
 opacity: 0.5;
} */

.menu {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
#menu-items {
  background: #121212;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#menu-items {
  padding: 22px;
  margin: 0 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
ul#menu-items li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  color: #939598;
  font: normal 12px/16px Gotham-Medium;
}
ul#menu-items li a {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul#menu-items li>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #76bd1c;
}
li.item {
  padding: 25px;
}
li.search {
  margin-left: 145px;
}
#category-list {
  width: 900px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* 
        margin-top: -380px;
         */
  background-color: #f7f6f5;
  position: relative;
  top: -380px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
/* li.products:hover #category-list{
        display: block;
      } */

#category-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.category-menu {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.category-menu {
  font: normal 12px/16px Gotham-Medium;
  color: #603913;
}
#category-menu-items {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#category-menu-items li {
  text-align: center;
}
.padding-left60 {
  padding-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<srcipt src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>


  <div class="cotnainer-fluid" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="row menu">
        <ul id="menu-items">
          <li class="item"><a href="Home.html">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item"><a href="About-Us.html">ABOUT US</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item products dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">PRODUCTS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item"><a href="Store.html">STORE</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item"><a href="Home.html/#contactUs-form">CONTACT</a> 
          </li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#">LOGIN</a>
          </li>


          <li class="item search"><a href="#"><i class="search-icon-header" style="font-size: 16px;"></i></a>
          </li>

          <li class="item basket"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 16px;"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h1 class="page-title">Some Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Nav items -->


  <div id="category-list">
    <div class="row category-menu">
      <ul id="category-menu-items">
        <li class="padding-left60">
          <a href="">
            <p>
              <img src="../image/bioorgo-biopesticides.png" alt="">
            </p>
            <p>BIOPESTIDES</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="padding-left60">
          <a href="">
            <p>
              <img src="../image/bioorgo-nutrients.png" alt="">
            </p>
            <p>NUTRIENTS</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="padding-left60">
          <a href="">
            <p>
              <img src="../image/bioorgo-biofertilizers.png" alt="">
            </p>
            <p>BIOFERTILIZERS</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="padding-left60">
          <a href="">
            <p>
              <img src="../image/bioorgo-seeds.png" alt="">
            </p>
            <p>SEEDS</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="padding-left60">
          <a href="">
            <p>
              <img src="../image/bioorgo-garden_Acc.png" alt="">
            </p>
            <p>GARDEN ACCESSORIES</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have a list of items in navbar, now on hovering on one of the list items i want to display a hidden div which contains another list of items which should be clickable.

> In the above code, When I hover on PRODUCTS link; a div shows up. Now, I want to click on items in this div!!!!

I guess I need to check for hasClass('show'), and if so then i should be able to hover and click on the div items.
Any suggestions or help on how to move forward with this?

Comment: create a working [snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) to demo the problem.

Comment: what is currently happening?

Comment: use `.show{ display: block  !important; }` as you have added `display: none` to div with id `#category-list` which will overwrite the class properties.

Answer (score 0):

Priority of ID selector is higher than class selector.
[Ref.](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

```
//Make sure this style is overwrite the style of #category-list
#category-list.show{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the style with the below one and try and adjust the position using top of category list

```
<style>
#category-list {
    width: 900px;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f7f6f5;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: -380px;*/
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}

    #category-list ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }

.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some work in that jsfiddle.

```
// Show sub-menu with jQuery
$("ul#menu-items li.products a, ul#menu-items li.products").hover(function(){
    console.log("show sub menu");
    $("#category-list").show();
});
// Hide sub-menu with jQuery
$("body *").not("#menu-items, li.products, li.products a, #category-list,     #category-list *, #category-menu-items, div.categories").hover(function(){
    console.log($(this)); // Log the elements that triggers hide of sub menu
    $("#category-list").hide();
});
```

Don't know the pure CSS sub-menu technique yet.

https://jsfiddle.net/mantisse_fr/p1eupdo3/1/